When I use brushes with autosmoothing, my mesh tears apart
In Blender 2,93 my mesh is hollow. When I try to round the edges in sculpt mode and use any brush with autosmoothing > 0 the sheets of which the mesh consists (I do not know how to name them) break apart from each other (gaps appear) and even start to curl. The same happens when I use ⇧ Shift + brush.


It never happens when there's no smoothing.
I am new with  blender. What can I do? Can I fill in the mesh and then hollow it again? The vertex net seems to be dense enough.

I just found a similar problem and this guy says it helped. The advice was Edit Mode on the original mesh, selecting all, and then doing * Merge > By distance*.
Where is this Merge?

What do you mean, “fill the mesh and make it hollow again”? All meshes are supposed to be hollow…

I would say the hole is already there, it’s just the edges are right next to each other so you don’t see it. Have you tried selecting all and merging by distance on the base mesh?

---- fill the mesh and make it hollow again”? All meshes are supposed to be hollow -------  in Freecad there is such an option.
-----------it’s just the edges are right next to each other so you don’t see it.----------
Hm. I do not see any difference, looks like next faces share an edge between them.
--------------- Have you tried selecting all and merging by distance on the base mesh? ------
Thank you for the advice, but I do not know about this procedure.

Select all in Edit Mode with A, thrn hit M > Merge > By Distance. This should merge the vertices lying on top of each other. It "looks" like the faces share an edge between them? Don't rely on the look, click on an edge, hit G and move it. If only one face gets distorted and there appears another edge in that space, the faces do not share an edge. And "in Freecad there is such an option": this is Blender, not Freecad. You cannot assume all softwares are the same, and especially CAD software is maybe similar but not the same as 3D modeling software.

Thank you very much. Found it. The mesh behaves totally different now.
----------------------- this is Blender, not Freecad -----------
Do you mean that there are no solid meshes in Blender?

Correct, a (closed) mesh is always hollow.

Thank you for enlightening me.

You know, you could use an online search engine to find some of this stuff, or better yet search the Blender manual. The merge by distance operator is not hard to find.

@GordonBrinkmann I would call that a complete answer if you wanna post it, but I’m not the OP.

@TheLabCat I would rather call it a duplicate question - unmerged vertices have been a problem here countless times. But I'm tired and have to sleep now and don't bother to find the duplicate which fits best.

You know, you could use an online search engine to find some of this stuff, --------------
That's right. There is online search and we really do not need such websites as this one.
